# Using Regex to pull value between html tags

Tags: html, regex, bash

So I know there is easier ways to do this, however I was given the code and asked to attempt to make it work. Rather than rewrite the entire thing I'd simply like to get this working.

So what it does is download the source code for the web page that displays when a person searches the app store. Once that is done I am attempting to pull the version of the app which comes across as the first line below

Once I get the code from the downloaded file I'd like it be placed in another file to be called for later use, however if this is an unnecessary step I am willing to remove it

I have a feeling I am missing something simple.

```
<span class="htlgb">4.72</span>

# connects to iTunes website with Casino/Manufacturers id 
curl https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=${address[$a]} > json
# puts just the  version from the json file into version file
grep -Po '(?<=<span class="htlgb"> ).*?(?=</span>)' json > version
# cuts out some data so we have just a version number
current_Version=`cat version | tr -d '"' | tr -d ',' | tr -d 'version:'`
```

Comment: If you need a working solution, please minimize the code to the part where it is not working. Provide the exact input string and expected output.

Comment: I don't mean to be rude but this is a very cut down version of the code. I showed the parts where I am having a problem. I did however show enough for someone to recreate it as the input is the first line(Stated in the Paragraph) and that is also the expected output

Comment: So, let's say you have `<span class="htlgb">4.72</span>`, what is the output? `4.72`? `grep -Po '(?<=<span class="htlgb">).*?(?=</span>)' <<< "<span class="htlgb">4.72</span>"` already gives you what you need then. See [the online demo](https://ideone.com/WLIPHz).

Comment: `grep -Po '<span class="htlgb">\K[0-9.]+' file` [will also work](https://ideone.com/h76Wtc).

Comment: The input is the curl return. That gets the html. I then need to thin the html down to 4.72

Comment: So, getting back to the starting point: ***what* is the input**?

Comment: Again if you navigate to any app on the google play store and check the page source code that would be the input. The particular one I am doing now is: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rubyseven.tropworldcasino

Comment: A question is offtopic if you do not provide the text *you have*.

Comment: I figured out what I need to based upon the answer someone else had given. I appreciate your help. I apologise for not giving you the thousand line HTML file that I had as I did not see it necessary for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not a bash pro, but this matches 3 groups to your desired html tag. All you need to add now, it so select the value from group 2.

```
(<span class=\"htlgb\">)(.*?)(</span>)
```

You can test it here: https://regex101.com/r/9RPycf/1

Comment: So how would I select that?

Answer (score 1):

Please don't use [regex to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858)! Use a true HTML parser like [Xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html) instead:

```
echo '<span class="htlgb">4.72</span>' | xidel -s - -e '//span[@class="htlgb"]'
4.72
```

I wouldn't use this path expression for the playstore website however, because there are a lot of these. I've used the [Spotify page](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spotify.music) as an example.

```
xidel -s https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spotify.music -e '//div[@class="hAyfc"][div
="Current Version"]/outer-html()'
<div class="hAyfc"><div class="BgcNfc">Current Version</div><span class="htlgb"><div class="IQ1z0d"><s
pan class="htlgb">8.5.40.195</span></div></span></div>
```

The version string `8.5.40.195` can be found within a `div` (with an attribute `class="hAyfc"`) that has a child `div` with the text `Current Version`.
Then it's as simple as selecting the `span` (text)node:

```
xidel -s https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spotify.music -e '//div[@class="hAyfc"][div="Current Version"]/span'
8.5.40.195

# or with your variable:

xidel -s https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=${address[$a]} -e '//div[@class="hAyfc"][div="Current Version"]/span'
```